# How to know Nest Protect device current status through android APIs

Tags: nest-api

Is any android API support for the following status of the nest smoke and carbon monoxide detect:
(1) When the device is on
(2) when the device is off (the batteries are removed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you follow the instructions provided by Nest Labs in their github account, you should be able to receive information from any nest device associated with your home.nest.com account. Create a nest developer account in console.developers.nest.com and add all devices you would like permissions for. then follow steps to receive a nest access token. with the token you can authenticate your account and initialize listeners. the smokeCo alarm listener should give you all the current info regarding the smoke alarm, last test, status etc.

Good luck.